# Google Cloud Endpoints Framework API Explorer doesn't work after migration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, endpoints

I migrated to Endpoints Framework 2.0 and it works locally but when I deploy to App Engine my endpoints API doesn't seem to work.

I'm supposed to be able to view my API using the explorer:

```
https://[PROJECT_ID].appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer
```

But when I open this page, there is an error in the backend:

```
/_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis : java.lang.NullPointerException at com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet.service(EndpointsServlet.java:71)
```

The API doesn't seem to work and opening the backend's webpage (index.html) gives the same error. I can't debug this because "EndpointsServlet.java" isn't part of my source code. How can I see the source for EndpointsServlet.java so I can debug this error? (All this used to work before migrating to Endpoints Framework).

Comment: how are you deploying it?

Comment: I deploy it with Android studio's "Deploy module to App Engine" button. My javac -version reports 1.7.0_79.

Comment: Android Studio's deploy isn't compatible with v2 you need to deploy manually via gradle until they update it

Comment: Android Studio can't deploy frameworks v2? Is that in writing somewhere? That's kinda a big deal. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: I found that info on one of their github projects, I dont remember what one off hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to tyczj. Frameworks v2 must be deployed manually via gradle by running:

```
appengineDeploy
```

In Android Studio, you can open the gradle sidebar and double-click :backend:Run Configurations:[appengineDeploy]

After doing this everything works.